# French sci fi novel: political chaos, VR technology, Islamic professor

Tags: story-identification, novel

Back in the 1990’s, I read a French novel that blew me away… but I cannot recall its name nor its author.

From what I remember: the world (France) was on the brink of political chaos. Extremisms were here: riots…
Some people could go into a game through VR technologies. And if I’m correct, at some point, the main protagonist was able to fight as a crusader in Jerusalem.
I also remember a wise professor (?) guided by a peaceful Islam.

If I’m correct, the photograph of the author on the back of the book was young and wore glasses (but it’s not 100% certain).

Comment: Based on your description, you may want to check out the author [Bernard Werber](https://www.goodreads.com/photo/author/70574.Bernard_Werber) - it says that photo is from 2009, in 1990s he would definitely match your description (young with glasses) - is the face familiar? He published a lot during the 1990s. He writes "realistic" sci-fi and I think also wrote something featuring videogames. Unfortunately large portion of his work was not translated and I do not speak French, so I can't help further.

Comment: Also, not the answer, but your question made me think of the novel Submission by Houellebecq and rediscover [this hilarious review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1193953038) on goodreads

Comment: Hello And thanks for your answer. 
Pretty sure it’s not Werber. As I’m French and I knew at that time this author. 
Submission is interesting and Im gonna check the review right away. Thanks a lot. My quest continues. I shall find this author!

Answer (score 4):

This is almost certainly *Le Dixième Cercle* by Guy Thuillier. The author was 27-28 when the book was published in 1999 ([source](https://www.babelio.com/auteur/Guy-Thuillier-II/111573)), and the back cover of the paper version features a photograph of him wearing glasses ([source](https://images.epagine.fr/860/9782290049860_4_75.jpg)). The story is set in Paris in 2099 (on the verge of civil war), and is about the main protagonist spending his time in virtual reality, until strange phenomenas and hallucinations start to happen in the real world around him.

It matches all the details you describe, except that the Muslim character is the protagonist's therapist, not a professor. However the character is framed as some sort of wise guide. Below are some excerpts from the book, automatically translated from French.

---

The book starts with characters observing from afar scenes of guerrilla warfare in the middle of Paris. Here is a scene from the first chapter:

> Throughout Paris, fighting between the APPLE rebels and the regular
> army continued. From their vantage point, Cartier and Borovitch
> couldn't see the fighters and barricades, or even the columns of
> armored vehicles moving up the main thoroughfares. But the explosions,
> suddenly illuminating a row of facades in a warm orange, very
> different from the icy light of the electric arches, gave a rough
> cartography of the derisory battle for the capital of the Province of
> France.

It also features a virtual reality game taking place in medieval Jerusalem, where gamers can choose to watch or to take part in a battle:

> His equipment - helmet, shroud, sword, shield - weighed a ton. He was
> literally baking inside, sweating profusely under the blazing sun. The
> serious business began when they came within range of the enemy's
> arrows. In his mind's eye, he recalled the arrow he had plunged into a
> crusader's shoulder on his first visit to *Jerusalem 1099*. After a
> few dozen meters, an arrow pierced the thigh of one of his neighbors,
> who collapsed with a groan.

The protagonist's therapist is Muslim ([Sufi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sufism)). At some point, the protagonist tries to argue with him about religion:

> – Momo, with all due respect, you make me laugh with your theories! And
> you, you don't go into religious delirium, do you? Who's the one who
> goes to Syria for Sufi courses on vacation? Isn't that completely
> irrational? Why should your Prophet be more legitimate than mine?

– but the therapist remains stoic. Then, the protagonist proceeds asking him more information about what is Sufism; the therapist obliges, explaining the spiritual aspect of it:

> – [...] The goal of the Sufi mystic is to achieve bliss. It's about getting as
> close as possible to the ultimate truth - which is God. To achieve
> this, we have to pierce the veil of reality as we perceive it, to find
> beyond it the principle of unity - God again. Obviously, this requires
> a long process of self-improvement, which takes place in progressive
> stages through esoteric initiation.